# Magento pagination not working (1.7.0.2)

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, pagination

I made an online-shop for a friend of mine. It works very well and everything is fine and so on.

But some days ago the Pagination stopped working. It worked fine for some months. Since then I haven´t changed something in the Code or elsewhere.

Google Chrome is showing me some errors on the online shop. Maybe they help you :)

Errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function www.historia-outlet.de/anhanger.html:885

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function www.historia-outlet.de/skin/frontend/default/theme152k/js/scripts.js:135

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function www.historia-outlet.de/skin/frontend/default/theme152k/js/vpager.js:73

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function www.historia-outlet.de/skin/frontend/default/theme152k/js/scripts.js:135
```

I´m not a Magento Expert but I have a litte experience.

Thanks for your help :)

PS: This is the shop I was talking about: [Online Shop][1]

[1]: http://www.historia-outlet.de/anhanger.html#%21___SID=U&p=3`enter preformatted text here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug gives a bit better answer

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).easyTooltip is not a function
TypeError: jQuery(...).jcarousel is not a function
```

It appears that a couple jQuery libraries were removed from the page and the code that calls them was not. The fatal js errors cause all js to stop working. Either add the scripts back in or remove the calls on the following lines.

```
anhanger.html line 885
scripts.js line 135
vpager.js line 73
```